# Cant get String value from Android Edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an edittext which i have pasted below:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:id="@+id/id_verification_code"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:drawablePadding="20dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:backgroundTint="?android:attr/colorBackground"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="40sp"
    android:hint="Enter Verification code"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/icon_lock_24" />
```

But unfortunately i can't seem to get the string value from the edit text When click on a button.

This is codes below to set The edittext and try to retrieve the string value when the user enters some value.

```
EditText edtVerify = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.id_verification_code);
String token = edtVerify.getText().toString();
```

When i click on the button i expect to see the logs but unfortunately nothing shows.

```
Button btnVerification = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnVerify);
    btnVerification.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Log.i("validToken", token);

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to get the value only when you need it that is on click of the button

```
Button btnVerification = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnVerify);
btnVerification.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String token = edtVerify.getText().toString();

            Log.i("validToken", token);

        }
});
```

so what you are doing at the moment is getting the value as soon as you have initialized the edittext in onCreate probably at which time your user would not have entered the value on the screen as the view is just getting created.

Getting it at the time of click ensures that whatever value you have entered in text is captured after the click.

Comment: thank you. that was simple and it got me thinking too much

Answer (score 0):

You should get text from edittext when press button.
Use this

```
Button btnVerification = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnVerify);
btnVerification.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        Log.i("validToken", edtVerify.getText().toString(););
    }
});
```

If you want to log text when user is typing add TextWatcher to Edittext like this

```
edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {


        }
    });
```